# Single sign-on working fine with OpenIDP but not with the ADFS

Tags: node.js, logging, single-sign-on, passport.js, adfs

I am beginner to nodejs and trying to get the single sign-on working. The single sign-on works fine for my app running on my local authenticated using OpenIdp. But, not for my app running on VM and integrated to company ADFS. I am not sure what is wrong here.

Below is the code related code.

app.js :

```
    'use strict';

    require('./appRequire');

    var config = appRequire('/config-bootstrap').config;
    var logger = appRequire('/lib/app-logger');
    var isAuthenticated = appRequire('routes/is-authenticated');

    var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
    var express = require('express');
    var morgan = require('morgan'); //express logger
    var path = require('path');
    var swig = require('swig');
    var app = express();
    // required for passport authentication
    var passportRoutines = appRequire('/lib/passport-routines');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true,
      limit: '50mb'
    }));
    app.use(session({
          secret: "this is not secret",
          resave: true,
          saveUninitialized: true
       }));
    var passport = passportRoutines.getPassport();
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/vendor/public'));
    app.use(busboy());

    app.use(morgan('combined', {
      stream: logger.stream,
      skip: function(req, res) {
        return res.statusCode  user object not available. Auth is not successful.")
            return res.redirect(APP_ROOT + '/not-authorised');
          }
          req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              return next(err);
            }
            res.redirect(APP_ROOT);
          });
        })(req, res, next);
      });



    var serv = require('./routes/serv');
    app.use(APP_ROOT, serv);

    var ROUTES = ['employees', 'accounts', 'activities', 'admin'];
    ROUTES.forEach(function (route) {
      app.all(APP_ROOT + '/' + route + '*', isAuthenticated);
      var routeModule = require('./routes/' + route);
      app.use(APP_ROOT + '/' + route, routeModule);
    });

    var errorHandler = require('./routes/errors');
    app.use(APP_ROOT, errorHandler.router);

    // 404 HANDLING
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var notFoundError = new Error('Page ' + req.url + ' cannot be found');
      notFoundError.status = 404;
      next(notFoundError);
    });

    // ERROR HANDLING

    app.use(errorHandler.errorHandler());


    swig.setDefaults({
      locals: {
        appAssetPaths: {
          'js': '/javascript',
          'js_vendor': '/javascript/vendor',
          'style': '/css/generated',
          'style_vendor': '/css/vendor',
          'static': '/icons'
        }
      }
    });

    app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

    if (!config.data_source === 'json') {
      throw 'data source not implemented (' + config.data_source + ')';
    }

    module.exports = app;
```

passport-routines.js :

```
    'use strict';
    var config = appRequire('/config-bootstrap').config;
    var passport = require('passport');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var logger = appRequire('lib/app-logger').AppLoger;

    function searchUser(username, passwordhash) {
       return (require('fs').readFileSync(config.passport.basic.auth_file,'utf-8').split('\n').map(function(e){
          return { name : e.split(':')[0], passwordhash : e.split(':')[1] };
       }).filter(function(e){
          return (e.name === username && e.passwordhash === passwordhash);
       }).length == 1);
    }

    function getCertificate(){
     if(config.passport.saml.cert){
         logger.info("using the certficate file :", config.passport.saml.cert);
         return fs.readFileSync(config.passport.saml.cert, 'utf-8')
     }else{
         logger.info("Cert property is not defnied");
         return null;
     }
    }

    function getPassportStrategy(){
      switch(config.passport.strategy){
        case "saml":
          var saml = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
          var saml_options = {
            entryPoint : config.passport.saml.entryPoint,
            issuer : config.passport.saml.issuer,
            acceptedClockSkewMs : config.passport.saml.acceptedClockSkewMs,
            callbackUrl : config.passport.saml.callbackUrl,
            signatureAlgorithm : 'sha256',
            cert: getCertificate(),
            identifierFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
          };
          if (config.passport.saml.cert) {
            saml_options['cert'] = fs.readFileSync(config.passport.saml.cert, 'utf-8');
          }
          return new saml(saml_options, function(profile, done) {
              logger.info(" profile retrieved from ADFS :", JSON.stringify(profile))
              console.log(" --> profile retrieved from ADFS :", JSON.stringify(profile))
              return done(null, {
                id : profile.uid,
                email : profile.email,
                displayName : profile.cn,
                firstName : profile.givenName,
                lastName : profile.sn,
              });
          });
        case "basic":
          var httpbasic = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
          return new httpbasic(function(username, password, done) {
            return done(null, searchUser(username, require('md5')(password)));
          });
        case "noauth":
          var noauth = appRequire("/lib/passport-noauth").Strategy;
          return new noauth();
        default:
          throw "No known passport strategy configured!";
      }
    }

    var isAuthorised = function(user){
        var data, authUsers;
        try{
            logger.info('User returned from ADFS :', JSON.stringify(user))
            console.log('--> User returned from ADFS :', JSON.stringify(user))
            data = fs.readFileSync(config.passport.saml.auth_users_file,'utf-8');
            authUsers = JSON.parse(data);
            logger.info('Authorised users :', authUsers);
        }catch(err){
            logger.error("Either authorised-users.json file does not exist or it not in the right format")
            logger.error(err);
        }

        return true;
    }

    var isUserAuthorised = function(user) {
      logger.info('user in passport-routines. js :', JSON.stringify(user))
      var DEFAULT_AUTH = function() {
        return true;
      };
      switch(config.passport.strategy){
        case "saml":
          return function() {
              var authorised = isAuthorised(user)
              return authorised
          };
        case "basic":
          return DEFAULT_AUTH;
        case "noauth":
          return DEFAULT_AUTH;
      }
    };

    exports.getPassport = function () {
       passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
          done(null, user);
       });
       passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
          done(null, user);
       });
       passport.use(getPassportStrategy());
       return passport;
    }

    exports.isUserAuthorised = isUserAuthorised;
```

The config I used for OpenIDP are:

```
    "passport" : {
        "strategy" : "saml",
        "saml" : {
          "entryPoint" : "https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php",
          "issuer" : "http://myapp.com",
          "acceptedClockSkewMs" : -1,
          "callbackUrl" : "https://myapp.com:8081/authenticated/",
         "auth_users_file":"/path/to/authorised-users.json"
        },
      }
```

Config used for VM and ADFS combination:

```
<pre><code>
 "passport" : {
    "strategy" : "saml",
    "saml" : {
            "path": "/",
            "entryPoint": "https://adfs.mycomapny.com/adfs/ls/",
            "cert": "/path/to/key.pem",
            "issuer": "https://myapp.com",
            "acceptedClockSkewMs": -1,
            "authnContext": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/windows",
            "identifierFormat": null,
            "callbackUrl": "https://myapp.com/authenticated/",
            "auth_users_file":"/path/to/authorised-users.json"
     },
  }
```

In the case local+OpenIDP, I am able to see the log `console.log(" --> profile retrieved from ADFS :"` with the values returned from the OpenIDP. But, the `logger.info(" profile retrieved from ADFS :"` does not print anything.
I am not sure why console.log works but not the logger.info is empty as `2016-03-01T16:54:30.670Z - info:  profile retrieved from ADFS :`.
Also, `console.log('--> User returned from ADFS :` logs the JSON of user data.

In the case of VM + ADFS, both the logs are empty. App goes to '/not-authorised' with this logged: "--> user object not available. Auth is not successful."

After including the identifierFormat in the SAML Options `identifierFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress'`, I am able to get the SAML response as success for both the cases. But, in case of OpenIDP, I can see the values like uid, givenName etc. as part of `saml:AttributeStatement` within the `saml:AttributeStatement`. But, in the case VM+ADFS, I am seeing the `EncryptedAssertion` only. Looks like I need to install some key from the IDP and use it as part of SAML Options.

Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Edited to add more details related to identifierFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress' in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

SAML normally uses SHA-1 as per the passport-saml readme.md.

Also there is a ADFS token signing certificate as per the page and the linked article by Tim Brody.

How is ADFS configured?

Are there any events in the ADFS event log?

If you use the Firefox SAML tracer, do you get claims back?

Comment: I don't have the specific details of ADFS configuration but I am able to get the authentication successful now. Still the user profile details are not available. ADFS logs are saying authentication successful. The SAML tracer shows the response back but it is `EncryptedAssertion`. I guess I need to install public key or certificate from the IDP(ADFS).

Comment: No - if it's encrypted, you should own the certificate. Somebody must have configured the certificate in ADFS.

Comment: Thanks @nzpcmad. You are right: it is generated on the machine hosting the app using sudo `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout app-key.pem -out app-cert.pem -days 3650`. The `app-cert.pem` was provided to the ADFS team. The `app-key.pem` is read into as a value to the `cert` in saml options. Not sure why am not able to get user profile details still. Any other suggestions ? Thanks.